# How to retrieve all items from a DynamoDB table with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following node js code that should list all items from a DynamoDB table,

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "../../libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "../../libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context) {
  const params = {
    TableName: "brands",

    KeyConditionExpression: "brandId = :brandId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":brandId": ''
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);
    return success(result.Items);
  } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
     return failure({ status: false });
  }
}
```

The id is in uuid format which when inserted from my node js was imported by using:

```
import uuid from "uuid";
```

then inserted to the table like:

```
brandId: uuid.v1()
```

Now when I query the items in the table I can only get only one record if and only if I hard coded the uuid of a record in the expression attribute value (either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified). So I thought about adding a regular expression to match all the uuids, my regular expression was copied from some solutions on the web but it didn't work, it was like the following:

```
[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}
```

and

```
\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b
```

and I have tried other examples but non of them worked, is it right to add a regular expression to get all the items, and if so what is the right regex for it?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score -3):

Use a Scan operation to get all items in a table.

From [the AWS Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan):

> The scan method reads every item in the table and returns all the data in the table. You can provide an optional filter_expression, so that only the items matching your criteria are returned. However, the filter is applied only after the entire table has been scanned.

Comment: Why use scan operations?

Comment: Scan operations would be the last resort, because of their costs and performance, please consult https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html

Comment: The question specifically is trying to retrieve all items from the table. A scan is the correct way to do so....